# Android. ScrollView "infinite" scroll

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` the height of the entire screen. The image displayed in it is of something similar to a ruler.

I would like to do something like scroll through a huge list in a `ScrollView` and while i'm scrolling I want the ruler to go along with the items in the list.

The problem I'll certainly come across will be an `OutOfMemory` exception, because of all the ruler ImageViews I'll need to display one under the other.

So my question is, is there a way by which i could use a single `ImageView`, or let's say a few,  5 or something like that that can be scrolled in a cycle. So when i scroll down and the last `ImageView` ends, the first one starts. Something like an "infinite loop" with no beginning and no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. I just had to use `ListViews`. Seems that they manage the content so it doesn't throw `OutOfMemory` exceptions

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html